# Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional VPN Configuration

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-mobile-6.5, ipsec, handheld

I am trying to connect the Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Professional to a L2TP/IPSec VPN server with given configuration:

```
Remote Gateway : xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
Authentication Method : Pre-shared key : xxxxxxxxxxxx
Mode : Aggressive
Phase-1 Proposal:  aes128-sha256 
DH Group : 5
Phase-2 Proposal:  aes256-sha1 
PFS:  enable
DH Group:   5

User-name: xxxxxxxxxx
Password: xxxxxxxxxx
```

Every time i try to connect, it gives error of wrong user-name and password. I have successfully used above mentioned details to connect from Desktop.

I have tried the following:

### https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwW8Mx7SYjo

### https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-setup-a-VPN-connection-on-devices-with-Windows-Mobile

Comment: Does the device support SHA2? Windows Mobile devices (Windows Embedded Handheld) do not support SHA2 before a defined AKU (35) has been implemented within the firmware: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2986556/windows-embedded-handheld-6-5-does-not-support-sha2

Answer (score 0):

Does the device support SHA2? Windows Mobile devices (Windows Embedded Handheld) do not support SHA2 before a defined AKU (35) has been implemented within the firmware: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2986556/windows-embedded-handheld-6-5-does-not-support-sha2.

See also: https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/Does-Windows-Embedded-HandHeld-support-SHA-256-certificates (as you linked a honeywell article).